# Changing records border color in a grid extjs3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a grid that i'm using to display records from a table in my database. In this table i have a field called "STATUS" that has values either 'ON' or 'OFF'. What i'm trying to do is give the record a border-color green in the grid if the value is ON and red border-color if the value is OFF. I tried everything such as the getRowClass method while changing the CSS in the extjs-all.css .  However i'm not being successful. I really appreciate some help.

```
 grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                        id:'users_gridpanel',
                        region:'center',
                        loadMask: {msg:"${tr.Loading}..."},
                        store: gridStore,
                        tbar:tlb,
                        cm: colModel,
                        stripeRows: true,
                        sm: _selctionModel,
                        plugins: [filters],
                        bbar:paging,
                        viewConfig:
                        {
                            forceFit: true,
                            headersDisabled:false
                        },


                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a column model for grid , in column model **status** column add **renderer** method for this and add value in div tag of html

```
renderer:function(val,b,c,d,e,f){
           if(val==ON){
              return "<div add color property here for div >"+val+"</div>"
             }else{
              return "<div add color property here for div >"+val+"</div>"
             }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not want you exactly need but I already done something similar with renderer function in the column, maybe you going to be able to use that too?

Here is my code:

```
 columns: [
   {header: "Color", dataIndex: "COLOR", width:100,
     renderer: 
       function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
           if(value =='ON')
                metaData.style = "background-color: rgb(255,255,255);";
           else
                metaData.style = "background-color: rgb(0,0,0);"
         return "";
       }                                        
  },
```

You can give a try with `border-color` instead of `background-color`

Hope this helps